# Is there an IntelliJ Python plugin for the community edition?

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea

I've been playing with the community edition of JetBrains ItelliJ IDEA since it came out, and I really like it; however, a lot of plugins seem to require the ultimate edition (or at least I think they do because of the com.intellij.modules.ultimate dependency). Is there a python plugin that doesn't require the ultimate edition? I'm developing django applications, so support for templates would be nice, but this isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of PyCharm 3.0, there is now a community edition of PyCharm. You can download it for free. It does not have all the features of the professional edition; however. Here is a comparison of the editions:

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/).